# Is it OK to perform long operations in ChannelInboundHandler.channelRead

Tags: java, netty

I'm using netty 4, and I'm trying to get used to their programming model. But here's a question that I haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer for in netty's documentation:

Is is alright to perform long operations in `ChannelInboundHandler.channelRead()`? If I do so, am I going to compromise the throughput of my application? Should I avoid doing that and use `channelRead()` only for enqueuing tasks into an `Executor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not ok to dod anything long running. You will need todo it on another thread then the IO Thread.